# Using props in React with styled components across components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a React component:

```
const StyledButton = styled.button`
    border: none;
    background: ${props => props.color};
    color: white;
    &:focus {
        outline: none;
    }
`;

const Button = (props) => {
    return (
        <StyledButton>{props.name}</StyledButton>
    )
};
```

and another component:

```
const NoteWindow = (props) => {
    return (
        <StyledNoteWindow className="NoteWindow">
            <StyledForm action="#" className="form">
                <StyledInput type="text" name="title" id="title" autoComplete="off" placeholder="Title" style={{fontSize: 60, fontWeight: 700}}/>
                <StyledInput type="text" name="content" id="content" autoComplete="off" placeholder="Content.." style={{fontSize: 20}}/>
            </StyledForm>
            <Button name="Discard" color="red"/>
            <Button name="Save" color="blue"/>
        </StyledNoteWindow>
    )
}
```

and I want the background of my button component to be the "color" attribute in the other element. 
How can I do that? (Everything is imported and exported)

Comment: Are you simply wanting `Button` to be colorable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, `Button` and `StyledButton` components accepts at least the following props, `name` and `color`.

Therefore, you will need to pass the props down to the `StyledButton` component:

```
const Button = ({ color, name }) => (
  <StyledButton color={color}>{name}</StyledButton>
);
```

Comment: @Roy glad to help! Do remember to always check the props, and only pass down the required ones!

Answer (score 0):

Destructure `name` to used as child/text of button, and spread the rest of the passed props to `StyledButton`.

```
const Button = ({ name, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <StyledButton {...props}>{name}</StyledButton>
  )
};
```